# Getting Error when trying to list Kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Apache Kafka and trying to list kafka topics. I'm using --bootstrap-server and the following command.

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
```

I am getting the following error when run the command.

```
[2022-11-22 17:15:10,646] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I also changed the server.properties file. I uncommented the listeners part and change it to the following.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

Comment: Are you sure you have started up kafka? You can do this with kafka-server-start.sh  <path_to_your_kafka>/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/config/server.properties

Comment: I think there is no need to start the Kafka first. But, i tried your solution and getting same error.

Comment: Undo your change in server.properties before you start kafka.

Comment: You do need to start the server. That's like trying to create a database table without a database.

Answer (score 1):

kafka-topics.sh specifies a bootstrap server of localhost:9092 and is not finding it there. You need to start kafka on localhost first.

1. Please undo your change to server.properties and
2. start zookeeper with

   zookeeper-server-start.sh <path_to_your_kafka>/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/config/zookeeper.properties
3. start kafka with

   kafka-server-start.sh <path_to_your_kafka>/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/config/server.properties

Comment: I reset the server.properties file, started the server but the session has been closed with the following message:  INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

Comment: @Ali Then there's some other error. Update your question with the full log

Comment: My guess is you havent started Zookeeper. Updated the answer to include that.

Comment: Or use kraft mode